# Npm build development build with react/typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

I created a TypeScript React app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

If I type "npm start" it creates a development server and creates development javascript files. But it is not good for me, because I want to serve my project from my own golang server. I found out "npm run build" is good for this purpose, because it creates the static javascript files what are necesary for running the project from my own server. But it is always creates a production build, how can I build a development build (no minifying etc)? I just could not find an answer to this.

Here is my package.json if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "mui-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.14",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.8",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want with the option `--no-minify`, so you can try :

```
npm run build --no-minify
```

If you want more options, you can take a look at the documentation with this command :

```
npm run build --help
```